# Yum update coreutils failed

Tags: centos, yum, coreutils, linux

I got error update coreutils.

Here is console log

```
root@server70 [~]# yum update coreutils
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile                  
 * cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6: xmlrpc.cln.cloudlinux.com    
Setting up Update Process                                   
Resolving Dependencies                                      
--> Running transaction check                               
---> Package coreutils.x86_64 0:8.4-31.el6 will be updated  
---> Package coreutils.x86_64 0:8.4-31.el6_5.2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution                              

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================
 Package          Arch          Version                  Repository                         Size 
=================================================================================================
Updating:                                                                                        
 coreutils        x86_64        8.4-31.el6_5.2           cloudlinux-x86_64-server-6        3.0 M 

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 3.0 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64.rpm                                       | 3.0 MB     00:03
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64                                               1/2
Error unpacking rpm package coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /bin/cat: cpio: rename
Unable to send message to PackageKit
coreutils-8.4-31.el6.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : coreutils-8.4-31.el6.x86_64                                                   1/2
  Verifying  : coreutils-8.4-31.el6_5.2.x86_64                                               2/2

Failed:
  coreutils.x86_64 0:8.4-31.el6                 coreutils.x86_64 0:8.4-31.el6_5.2

Complete!
```

Comment: Have you got enough memory and disk space?

Comment: I have got 80gb fre disk space and 10gb free memory

Comment: problem solved with "chattr -i /bin/cat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, problem solved with:

```
chattr -i /bin/cat
```